# Why is my boolean value an instance of int?

Tags: python, boolean

`x` is of type `bool`. So why does my code have the output `True`? I am new to Python. What's going on here?

Code:

```
x = True
print(isinstance(x, int))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands Is this the appropriate dupe? Equality does not imply subclass-relationships. edit: just noticed that the question body extends beyond the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Quoting from the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> Booleans ([bool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool))
>   These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values `False` and `True` are the only Boolean objects. **The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type**, and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings `"False"` or `"True"` are returned, respectively.

Answer to comment:

> Would it also return `True` if you did `isinstance(bool, int)`?

No. `True` and `False` are *instances* of `bool` and therefore instances of the parent class `int`, but `bool` itself is not an *instance* of `int`. Being a class it's an instance of `type` and a *subclass* of `int`.

```
>>> isinstance(bool, int)
False
>>> isinstance(bool, type)
True
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Comment: Would it also return True if you did isinstance(bool, int)?

Comment: @dfundako no, see edit.

Comment: thax dfundako.....

Answer (score 0):

Because booleans are a subtype of integers. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

Comment: Really doesnt add anything to the answer that was already here.

Comment: Agreed, we must have been posting at the same time. Feel free to delete.